# SNR measurement for a BPSK/QPSK signal

Tags: software-defined-radio, rf-power, gnuradio, testing, snr

I have created a software (gnuradio) that performs modulation/demodulation and supports a number of modulation schemes and error correcting codes. I'm in the process of evaluating the BER vs SNR for this software by using a secondary industrial-grade hardware. This device can measure the BER. Unfortunately, the device does not have the capability of measuring the input signal SNR, which means I have to measure it manually. At the moment, I'm thinking of using a spectrum analyzer. Basically, I will compare the signal level relative to the noise floor and derive the SNR (simple subtraction since everything is in dBs). However, I was looking for suggestions on more elegant methods of doing this and what type of hardware would be required.

Comment: Is this some kind of lab setup with a known message and a simulated AWGN channel? In that case it's not usually necessary to measure the SNR since the signal and noise powers can be read right off the test equipment.

Comment: The message is known. The RF signal is transmitted through an SMA cable so the noise is a physical one.

Answer (score 1):

FLDigi will calculate the SNR for a PSK31 signal based on the spectrum scope.